# Flask loop takes long time to complete

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this loop in my app.py. For some reason it extends the load time by over 3 seconds. Are there any solutions?

```py
import dateutil.parser as dp

# Converts date from ISO-8601 string to formatted string and returns it
def dateConvert(date):
    return dp.parse(date).strftime("%H:%M @ %e/%b/%y")

def nameFromID(userID):
    if userID is None:
       return 'Unknown'
    else:
       response = requests.get("https://example2.org/" + str(userID), headers=headers)
       return response.json()['firstName'] + ' ' + response.json()['lastName']

logs = []
response = requests.get("https://example.org", headers=headers)
for response in response.json():
    logs.append([nameFromID(response['member']), dateConvert(response['createdAt'])])
```

Comment: What do `nameFromID` and `dateConvert` do? (Please add them to your question.) For all we can know, they are both frontends to `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Are you sure that the loop is the problem? Maybe it's the `requests.get` call or any of the calls inside the loop (`logs.append`, `nameFromId`, `dataConvert`)? If your code is slow and you're not sure why, look into profiling in Python - there are probably a lot of useful tools for your specific Web framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It extends the load time by over 3 seconds because it does a lot of unnecessary work, that's why.

- You're not using `requests` Sessions. Each request will require creating and tearing down an HTTPS connection. That's slow.
- You're doing another HTTPS request for each name conversion. (See above.)

  - You're parsing the JSON you get in that function twice.
- Whatever `dp.parse()` is (`dateutil`?), it's probably doing a lot of extra work parsing from a free-form string. If you know the input format, use `strptime`.

Here's a rework that should be significantly faster. Please see the TODO points first, of course.

Also, if you are at liberty to knowing the member id -> name mapping doesn't change, you can make `name_cache` a suitably named global variable too (but remember it may be persisted between requests).

```
import datetime
import requests

INPUT_DATE_FORMAT = "TODO_FILL_ME_IN"  # TODO: FILL ME IN.


def dateConvert(date: str):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, INPUT_DATE_FORMAT).strftime(
        "%H:%M @ %e/%b/%y"
    )


def nameFromID(sess: requests.Session, userID):
    if userID is None:
        return "Unknown"
    response = sess.get(f"https://example2.org/{userID}")
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    return "{firstName} {lastName}".format_map(data)


def do_thing():
    headers = {}  # TODO: fill me in
    name_cache = {}
    with requests.Session() as sess:
        sess.headers.update(headers)

        logs = []
        response = sess.get("https://example.org")
        for response in response.json():
            member_id = response["member"]
            name = name_cache.get(member_id)
            if not name:
                name = name_cache[member_id] = nameFromID(sess, member_id)
            logs.append([name, dateConvert(response["createdAt"])])
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for my messy code. I'm newbie to python and flask overall. Thank you for your response. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: It's fine, no need to apologize (though as you could see, more context made answering actually possible :-) )! Welcome to SO, Python, and Flask! Glad I could help.